# How to use ShellExecute to open html files in Windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm trying to open some html file with the default browser from my code.

I use the following code:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "HELP\index.html",
            NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

And include header "Windows.h". But ShellExecuter:identifier not found error comes up and compilation fails.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. How can I make ShellExecute work, or more to the point, how can I open a html file from my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to use ShellExecute, you should include Shellapi.h and link with Shell32.lib library

Comment: Thanks! But I still have trouble since "open" and the link in quotation gives the error "cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR' ".

Comment: Use `L"open"` to specify a wide string literal

Comment: try to do something like: ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), TEXT("HELP\index.html"),
            NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

On WinXP

```
ShellExecute( NULL, NULL, "HELP\index.html", NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

and as well

```
ShellExecute( NULL, "call", "HELP\index.html", NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

both work fine.

Whereas on Window-7 (starter) only

```
ShellExecute( NULL, "open", "HELP\index.html", NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

is possible.

XP seems not to know "open" and Win-7 not to know "call".
I used the MINGW for all the building.